# Unable to set background image of scene in AndEngine?

Tags: android, andengine, live-wallpaper

I am trying to add an image to the background in wallpaper activity. But I am unable to do so, can some one suggest some way to do it, here is my code :

> menuBackgroundTexture = new BitmapTextureAtlas(getTextureManager(),
>   2*CAMERA_WIDTH, 2*CAMERA_HEIGHT, TextureOptions.DEFAULT);
>
> menuBgTexture = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(this.menuBackgroundTexture,
>   this, "land.png", 0, 0);

After tht I tried using

> this.menuBackgroundTexture.load();
>   but it is not working, I also tried following code 
>   SpriteBackground bg = new SpriteBackground(new Sprite(0, 0,
>   menuBgTexture,this.getVertexBufferObjectManager()));
>
> mScene.setBackground(bg);

This is also not working, please help me out.

Comment: One of the really annoying things i figured out was if the image file you are trying to use is too big then Android does not report an error however at the same time it does not display the image aswell. How big is you land.png file?

Comment: @SeahawksRdaBest its 771 kB, and I also make sure the dimension is also correct.

Comment: did you try using a smaller image to test it?

Comment: I did try that... but it is not working, any other suggestion ??

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a way to do that. Here is the code for the same :

> final BitmapTexture backgroundTexture = new
>   BitmapTexture(this.getTextureManager(), new IInputStreamOpener() {
>               @Override
>               public InputStream open() throws IOException {
>
> ```
>             return getAssets().open("gfx/background1.jpg");
>         }
>     });
>     backgroundTexture.load();
>     backgroundTextureRegion = TextureRegionFactory.extractFromTexture(backgroundTexture); final
> ```
>
> Sprite background = new Sprite(CAMERA_WIDTH / 2f -
>   backgroundTextureRegion.getWidth() / 2f, CAMERA_HEIGHT / 2f -
>   backgroundTextureRegion.getHeight() / 2f, backgroundTextureRegion,
>   this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
>         mScene.attachChild(background);

I hope it helps some one else.

Answer (score 0):

@Rahul, also work below code for wallaper activity in my wallpaper service

```
public class MagicWallpaper extends BaseLiveWallpaperService {

private TextureRegion region;

@Override
public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {
    calculateWidthAndHeight();
    Camera mCamera = new Camera(0, 0, Helper.GAME_WIDTH, Helper.GAME_HEIGHT);
    EngineOptions engOptions = new EngineOptions(true,
            ScreenOrientation.PORTRAIT_FIXED, new FillResolutionPolicy(),
            mCamera);
    return engOptions;
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private void calculateWidthAndHeight() {
    Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE))
            .getDefaultDisplay();
    Helper.GAME_WIDTH = display.getWidth();
    Helper.GAME_HEIGHT = display.getHeight();
}

@Override
public void onCreateResources(
        OnCreateResourcesCallback pOnCreateResourcesCallback)
        throws Exception {

    BitmapTextureAtlas atlas = new BitmapTextureAtlas(getTextureManager(),
            600, 1024);
    region = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(atlas,
            this, "wall.png", 0, 0);
    atlas.load();
    pOnCreateResourcesCallback.onCreateResourcesFinished();
}

@Override
public void onCreateScene(OnCreateSceneCallback pOnCreateSceneCallback)
        throws Exception {
    mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new FPSLogger());
    Scene dScene = new Scene();
    dScene.setBackground(new SpriteBackground(new Sprite(0, 0, region,
            getVertexBufferObjectManager())));
    pOnCreateSceneCallback.onCreateSceneFinished(dScene);
}

@Override
public void onPopulateScene(Scene pScene,
        OnPopulateSceneCallback pOnPopulateSceneCallback) throws Exception {
    pOnPopulateSceneCallback.onPopulateSceneFinished();
}
```

}